# Java - SendGrid Parse API in Java

Tags: java, ruby, http, sendgrid

I'm developing a small mail client and rely on SendGrid for sending emails. However, I have trouble receiving correctly the e-mails. SendGrid posts the email to an url, and then I'm trying to parse it using the JsonNode, but the problem is the text of the email doesn't come out as expected (strange characters coming up for french/german characters). Is there anyone who successfully used SendGrid to receive emails from SendGrid in Java? Thanks!

This will not work out in Java (see comments below), however I've found a way to do it using Ruby. This means I have to somehow call a ruby script from my Java code and get back the correctly parsed e-mail. Could somebody give some hints on how to do this? I'm thinking of somehow connecting from Ruby to the POST url, retrieve the email from the form and parse it. How can I achieve this? My knowledge in Ruby is pretty limited. Thank you!

Comment: can you elaborate more with the characters your app is receiving. An example would be great. Also are you using Tomcat or something like jetty?

Comment: So I'm trying to test the application by sending e-mails from my gmail account. If I set gmail to use utf-8, it's all good, the characters show up correctly when I'm reading the email from my application. But if I don't do that, then I get some wrong/strange characters, such as "ZÃ¯Â¿Â½rich", when I actually sent "Zürich". When an email is received, SendGrid posts the email to a url and I read it in my application through a DynamicForm (import play.data.DynamicForm). I have checked the charset of the message and in this case it is ISO-8859-1, but from the form I already get a Java string.

Comment: Which I'm afraid already ruins a possible conversion to UTF-8. What do you think?

Comment: Why can't you convert the string?

    `String s = "some text here";`
    `byte[] b = s.getBytes("UTF-8");`
    `s = new String(b, "US-ASCII");`

Comment: I've already tried: byte[] msg = message.getBytes("UTF-8");     message = new String(msg, "UTF-8"); but it's the same result. I've also tried with ISO-8859-1 in the getBytes() method, still wrong result. I don't want to convert it to US-ASCII as it will lose the special characters.

Comment: Right, that was just an example on how to convert a string. You should be getting a "charsets" param with the webhook post that will tell you what charsets are in the email.

Comment: Yes, I do have that. But the problem is that when I get the mail body message from the DynamicForm, I already get it as a Java String (JsonNode is basically giving a key-value pairing of parameters): String message = form.get("text"); So at this point how can I actually revert back to the original bytes and convert it to UTF-8? The original encoding is "ISO-8859-1", according to the charsets parameter.

Comment: byte[] msg = message.getBytes(envChar.get("html").getTextValue());
message = new String(msg, "UTF-8");                                         This yields "Z?rich".

Comment: I discovered it will not work because by the time I get the first string from the posted form, the byte array is already altered using the default java String encoding.

Comment: In that case you'll need to specify the encoding somewhere in the request or the DynamicForm before you retrieve the values. It would help to see your code but you want to do something like `request.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-1");`

Comment: routes is set as following:                                         POST /getmail  controllers.Application.getmail()  and then the method is                     public static Result getmail() {

  final DynamicForm form = form().bindFromRequest();                            ...

Comment: The dynamic form api is here:http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/java/play/data/DynamicForm.html It doesn't seem to have anything like that

Comment: I was actually thinking of something like connecting manually to that url and retrieve the bytes with a BufferedReader. Do you think it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run a ruby script from java you can do so using the ProcessBuilder class.

Here is a simple example: http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util/from-runtime.exec-to-processbuilder.html

Make sure your ruby script reads commands from the execution arguments and you should be good to go.

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec('ruby yourscript.rb {"json" : true}');
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way in Ruby to connect to an url and get the data posted to that url? This is basically what I have to do in the Ruby script.